# How can I fix my Python rock paper scissors game code?

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer and I just don't understand why my rock paper scissors program doesn't work, it worked previously but I tried adding a step to repeat if the user presses r. Where did I screw up?

This first program is before I tried to add the restart. It works as I expect.

```
import random
options = ('Rock','Paper','Scissors')
player_score = 0
computer_score = 0



def game(player, computer):
    
    global player_score
    global computer_score
    
    if player == computer:
        print(f"Both You and the Computer chose the same option {player}, It\'s a tie!")
        
    elif player == 'Rock':
        if computer == 'Paper':
            player_score += 1
            print(f'Paper covers the rock, you win 1 point, your score is {player_score}.')
        elif computer == 'Scissors':
            player_score += 1
            print(f'Rock smashes the scissors, you win 1 point, your score is {player_score}.')
            
    elif player == 'Scissors':
        if computer == 'Rock':
            computer_score += 1
            print(f'Rock smaches the scissors, computer wins 1 point, your score is {player_score}')
        elif computer == 'Paper':
            player_score += 1
            print(f'Scissors cut the paper, you win 1 point, your score is {player_score}.')
            
    elif player == 'Paper':
        if computer == 'Rock':
            player_score += 1
            print(f'Paper covers the rock, you win 1 point, your score is {player_score}.')
        elif computer == 'Scissors':
            computer_score += 1
            print(f'Scissors cut the paper, computer wins 1 point, your score is {player_score}.')
            

while True:
    if player_score == 10:
        print('*' * 30, '\nYour Score reached 10, You Win!', '*'*30)
        exit()
    elif computer_score == 10:
        print('*' * 30, '\nComputer Score reached 10, You Lose!', '*'*30)
        exit()
        
    player_choice = input('Please choose Rock, Paper, Scissor or Q for quit: ').lower()
    computer_choice = random.choice(options)
    
    if player_choice == 'quit':
        print('FINISH!')
        exit()
    elif not player_choice in options:
        print('Wrong Option!, please try again')
                
    else:
        game(player_choice, computer_choice)
```

it is a rock scissor paper game in python
the code doesn't work properly, I don't where is the error in my code?

Comment: I'm confused - you said that this script is the one where it worked? Can you post the version that does not work?

Comment: Also full stack trace plz!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what doesn't work? Does the program show error? Do you get unexpected output?

Comment: when i run the code it gives me for every option i enter the same answer ('Wrong Option!, please try again')

Comment: please try it in your idle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your options to `options = ('rock','paper','scissors')`, or remove `.lower()` in `player_choice`.

Otherwise the check `elif not player_choice in options:` will never evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition for `rock` increases the player score no matter what.

Other than that it's not possible to answer your question because you're not posting the version of the code where you repeat the game.

Comment: nice observation. But I think that is probably beside the point. The most I can speculate is that the author may have forgotten to re-instantiate the global variables. But this is just my speculation.

Comment: when i run the code it gives me for every option i enter the same answer ('Wrong Option!, please try again')

Comment: you need to try it in your idle

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @remooheshmat You are storing player_choice in with `.lower()`and then comparing with capitalized options. It will never match no matter what the input is.

Comment: but while writing the option quit, it doesn't work and gives me wrong option

Comment: Can you post the code after you fixed the above?

Comment: I fixed this line>>>>>>>
player_choice = input('Please choose Rock, Paper, Scissor or quit: ').capitalize()

Comment: Now it will capitalize first letter of whatever you input. i.e. `quit` becomes `Quit` . You need to change the check for quit accordingly: `if player_choice == 'Quit'`

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeesssssss, you're right, many thanks, you helped me alot